# dfs to implement a graph, python

Tags: python, graph, depth-first-search

I was trying to implement a graph using dfs in python to find all the possible path from 'A' to 'F'. 
The graph is:

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['A', 'D', 'E'],
         'C': ['A', 'F'],
         'D': ['B'],
         'E': ['B', 'F'],
         'F': ['C', 'E']}
```

And the following is my code:

```
def dfs_path(graph,start,end):
    res = []
    dfs(graph,start,end,[],res)
    return res
def dfs(graph,start,end,path,res):
    path+=[start]
    if start == end:
        res+=[path]
    elif not graph.has_key(start):
        return
    else:
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                dfs(graph,node,end,path,res)
print dfs_path(graph,'A','F')
```

by process the print, I did not get what I want, but instead, I get `[['A', 'B', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'C']]`

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code, and if is possible, I would like to know the correct way to write this code with the same format.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic problem is that there is only one path. When you make the recursive call to `dfs`, it modifies `path`.  When the call returns, it does not restore the old value of `path`.  The way around this is to pass a *copy* of `path` to `dfs`.  Note the `path[:]` in the recursive call.

The second problem is that when you do find a path, you are concatenating it with `res`, whereas you actuall want to append it to `res`.

In the code below, I have eliminated the check on whether `start` is a key in `graph`.  There is no way it could have been passed to the function without being a key in `graph`.

```
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
         'B': ['A', 'D', 'E'],
         'C': ['A', 'F'],
         'D': ['B'],
         'E': ['B', 'F'],
         'F': ['C', 'E']}

def dfs_path(graph,start,end):
    result = []
    dfs(graph,start,end,[],result)
    return result

def dfs(graph,start,end,path,result):
    path+=[start]
    if start == end:
        result.append(path)
    else:
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                dfs(graph,node,end,path[:],result)
print(dfs_path(graph,'A','F'))
```

This prints

```
[['A', 'B', 'E', 'F'], ['A', 'C', 'F']]
```

which looks right to me.

I would say that you got the function basically correct, but you need to review technicalities of python lists (and probably mutable data structures in general.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your backtracking.  The search starts out with A -> B -> D, and at D it reaches a dead end, since the only successor is B which has already been visited.  So it backs up, but you have not removed D from res.  It just stays there, so when it continues with E -> F, you still have D in your result.

Comment: My suggestion is to use a `set` to keep track of the nodes you've visited.  Add `start` to the set at the beginning of `dfs`.  When iterating over the successors of `start`, skip successors that are members of the set.  Otherwise recurse, and if a solution is found return `[start] + solution`.  If you exit the loop without returning, return `None`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DFS algorithm with iteration.

```
def dfs(graph, start):

    vertex=start

    visited, stack = [vertex], [vertex]  #add start index to both visited and stack   

    while stack:    #while stack is not empty
        #for each of the children of current vertex we find the first non visited child and add it to visited as well as stack

        for i,each in enumerate(graph[vertex]):  
            if each not in visited:
                visited.append(each)
                stack+=[each]    #push the element to stack if it is visited
                vertex=each      #change current vertex to last visited vertex
                break            #since the stack keeps track of the order of elements we can jump to children of current vertex.
            else:
                #if the length of children of a vertex is reached and all children are visited then pop the last element from stack
                if i==len(graph[vertex])-1:   
                    vertex=stack.pop() 
                    break
                else:
                    continue    #continue till the end to check if all the children of current vertex are visited
    return visited
graph = {'A': ['B', 'C'],
     'B': ['A', 'D', 'E'],
     'C': ['A', 'F'],
     'D': ['B'],
     'E': ['B', 'F'],
     'F': ['C', 'E']}
dfs(graph,'A')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Last In First Out
def dfs(G,Source,Goal):
    stack=[]
    stack_visited_result=[]
    stack.append(Source)
    stack_visited_result.append(Source)
    while len(stack)>0:
        print("**********STEP-",len(stack),"**********")
        r=0
        v=stack[-1]
        print("The current stack is ",stack);
        if(len(G.get(v))<=0):
            print("No key value for the top of the stack",x)
            stack.pop()
            v=stack[-1]
            print("After popping stack",stack)
        print ("top of the stack = " , v)
        for x in G[v]:
            if x not in stack_visited_result:
                r=1
                print ("value of x(ADJACENT VERTICES) " , x)
                stack.append(x)
                print("stack ",stack)
                if(stack[-1]==Goal):
                    print("--DESTINATION REACHED----")
                    print("RESULT FOR DFS ",stack_visited_result)   
                    quit()
                stack_visited_result.append(x)
                print("stack-visited ",stack_visited_result)
                break
        if(r is not 1):
                print("already visited so,pop the element")
                stack.pop()             
G={1:[2,3],2:[4,5,6],3:[],4:[],5:[7],6:[],7:[8],8:[]}
dfs(G,1,3)




This code will be used in case of directed graph
```